# How to find the minimum product of two or more quantities when their sum is given?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, maxima-minima

Suppose we have been given $ \sum_1^n x_i = S $

How will we find $x_i $  such that  $  \prod_1^n x_i $ is minimum?

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Edit : Sorry, my mistake. All $x_i$ are positive.

Comment: Have you heard of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes but I don't think that helps here.

Comment: Yes, it does.  The product of the number is the $n^{th}$ power of the geometric mean.

Comment: @RossMillikan That would give the upper bound of the product, not the lower bound.

Comment: @Raghav:  As Mark Fischler says, the question does not make sense for a minimum.

Comment: @Raghav I don't think so. Just the minimum does not exist, See my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yeah, I guess it doesn't make sense. It will be so close to 0 that it isn't worth it to find it.

Comment: @Raghav Which says that the minimum does not exist. In this the sense!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant finding $x_i$ such that the product is maximum, not minimum, since for a minimum, just take one of the $x_i$ to be zero.  Also, the problem makes sense only if you restrict to non-negative $x_i$.

So for some fixed $S$ we are trying to find $x_i$ such that $\sum x_i = S$ and $\prod x_i$ is as large as it can be.

There is a theorem that the geometric mean of a set of numbers $GM(\{x_i\})$ is less than or equal to the arithmetic mean $AM(\{x_i\})$; it is sometimes called the AM-GM theorem.  The geometric mean is the $n$-th root of the product of the numbers: $GM(\{x_i\})=\left(\prod x_i)\right)^{1/n}$.

Then 
$$ \left(\prod x_i)\right)^{1/n} \leq \frac1n \sum x_i = \frac{S}n \\
\prod x_i \leq \left( \frac{S}n \right)^n 
$$
When each of the $x_i = \frac{S}n$, this bound is exactly achieved.  Therefore, the desired $\{x_i\}$ happens when they are all equal to $\frac{S}n$.

Comment: No, I do not mean maximum. I want to find the product such that it is minimum. I have mentioned that $x_i$ are positive.

Comment: In that case, you can get arbitrarily close to $0$ bby making one of the entries very close to $0$ and the others $S/(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum of the products, but the infimum of the products is $0$.

*Proof.* By assumption all products are positive. Let an  $\epsilon\in\> ]0,S[\>$ be given, and put
$$x_1:=\epsilon,\qquad x_k:={S-\epsilon\over n-1}\quad(2\leq k\leq n)\ .$$
Then $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=\epsilon+(n-1){S-\epsilon\over n-1}=S$, and
$$0<\prod_{k=1}^n x_k=\epsilon\left({S-\epsilon\over n-1}\right)^{n-1}\leq\epsilon\left({S\over n-1}\right)^n\ .$$
As $n$ and $S$ are fixed the RHS of $(1)$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $\epsilon$ small enough. This proves that
$$\inf\prod_{k=1}^n x_k=0\ .$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt, wouldn't $\sum_1^n x_i $ get greater than S when I choose $\epsilon$ really small as I will have $S+ \frac{S}{2}$ for n=3.

Answer (score 0):

Does not exist.

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$ can be less than all positive number, but $\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k>0$.

Try $x_1=x_2=...=x_{n-1}\rightarrow0^+$ and $x_n\rightarrow S$.

Comment: sorry for wasting you wasting your time. I forgot to mention that all $x_i$ are positive. I've just edited it.

Comment: @Raghav I fixed my post. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Fischler does the general case, but it may be instructive just to consider the case of $n=2$.  Let the numbers be $a,b$.  We are given $S=a+b$ and asked to choose $a,b$ so the product is maximized.  The product $P=ab=a(S-a)=Sa-a^2$.  We can take the derivative and set to zero, getting
$$\frac {dP}{da}=\frac d{da}(Sa-a^2)=S-2a$$
If we set this to zero, we see $a=\frac S2$ and the second derivative test shows this is a maximum.

Now that we have it for two numbers, informally we should make any pair the same.  If we have $n$ numbers with two different, we can increase the product by changing each to the average of the two.  This needs some work to be a proof, but it should convince you.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this, but I want to find the minimum product, not maximum.

Comment: As Mark Fischler says, you can get the product arbitrarily close to zero by taking one of the $x_i$ very small.  If you prohibit zero, there is no lower bound.